# What is the difference between the image and media directories in a theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

When looking through Magento 2 themes, the directory structure include the directories `images` and `media`.  It seems like image files (png, gif, etc) could go into either directory.

What are the differences between each directory and what types of files should go into each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition media is a super set of image.
So images in svg,png,jpg,gif... should be in images folder.
Audio, video or other non-image media can be saved in media.

However, Can I know which folder you are looking at? Most of the time, the structure  of those file are just arranged by the module author, and it's not always "true".

Comment: I was following the directions for a new theme from the M2 documentation.  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html

Comment: ok, In the media, put the those media file like preview.png, video. In the image you can add you theme image inside which means like icon sprite picture or other decoration for you theme.